# Perl - передача данных объекта конструктору другого класса

Tags: perl, классы, ооп, объекты

Добрый день!
Вопрос о передаче данных объекта (переменные объекта и т.п.) в конструктор другого объекта.

Например мы имеем класс MyClass

```
package MyClass;
use parent qw/BaseClass/;
use Calc;

# конструктор
sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_); # используем конструктор базового класса
   return bless $self, $class;
}
# возвращаем объект класса Calc
sub calculate {return Calc->new($self)}
1;


package Calc;

sub new {
    my ($class, $self) = @_;
    $class = ref $class||$class;
    return bless {%$self}, $class;
}
```

Интересует строка из класса Calc

> **return bless {%$self}, $class**

Правильно ли так делать? Или есть более удобный метод?

Comment: А если внутри self есть ссылки/дескрипторы? В некоторых случаях может понадобиться "глубокое копирование".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это достаточно правильный *способ*. Для полного глубокого копирования обычно используют Clone, Storabe и т.п.

Но более правильным *подходом* будет передавать разыменованный/конированный хеш, а не делать это в bless-е.

```
-sub calculate {return Calc->new($self)}
-return bless {%$self}, $class;

+sub calculate {return Calc->new({%$self})}
+return bless $self, $class;
```